# Faster jquery selector for finding a number of TD elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance

I have a table where each row has 13 TD elements. I want to show and hide the first 10 of them when I toggle a link. These 10 TD elements all have an IDs with the prefix "foo" and a two digit number for its position (e.g., "foo01").  What's the fastest way to select them across the entire table?

```
$("td:nth-child(-n+10)")
```

or

```
$("td[id^=foo]")
```

or is it worth concatenating all of the ids?

```
$("#foo01, #foo02, #foo03, #foo04, #foo05, #foo06, #foo07, #foo08, #foo09, #foo10")
```

Is there another approach I should be considering as well?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem or are you just curious?

Comment: How many rows are in this table?  The IDs should only be used once, otherwise you have invalid HTML.

Comment: You're right, of course, about the IDs being used only once. I'm cleaning up some code that did not abide by that rule. I suppose I need to structure the HTML well first before figuring out why the JavaScript-enabled behaviors aren't doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 $("td:lt(10)")
```

I say this because you have ids which *should* be unique, meaning one row.

You could also use `$("tr").find("td:lt(10)")` for multiple rows...but keep those IDs unique.

But keep something in mind here, the speed of the selector is going to have *minimal impact* here.  Redrawing a table means a lot of reflow calculations by the browser (this column is how wide based on all text, what wraps, etc). **That's**  what's going to eat your time in this operation, the selector won't have a huge performance impact since the vast majority of processing time for this will be spent after it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess the find within the context of the $("tr") allows me to use the less than selector among the td elements of a single row.

Answer (score 1):

What if you added all of them to one class?  Or you could use "rel" maybe...just thinking that having one common identifier might speed things up.

Comment: I actually like the idea of giving everything that I'm going to hide/show a single class to identify it.